# Smarty.class.php error

Tags: php, html, smarty

I'm setting up the smarty, and it seems to work fine, new html was generated properly but there is one error message as follows:

```
"Notice: Undefined property: Smarty::$complie_dir in 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/Smarty-3.1.18/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 705".
```

It seems like there is some problem in Smarty.class.php contents.

Any ideas, please.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong...

Comment: Are you using a dev version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to access `Smarty::$complie_dir` but it property is named `compile_dir` not `complie_dir`.

However it seems it won't work anyway because you use Smarty 3.1.18 and:

> As of Smarty 3.1 the attribute $compile_dir is no longer accessible directly. Use getCompileDir() and setCompileDir() instead.

So you should use those 2 methods to get or change compile directory